# sql query to get the transaction for all the users having specific timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have sql table structure as follows:

```
id INT(11),
amount DOUBLE(10,2),
createdAt DATETIME,
user_id INT(11),
tx_status INT(11).
```

value of tx_status can be 1 (credit) , 2 (debit) and 3(settled). Now what I want is , I want all the latest transactions of all the users where transaction createdAt is greater than last createdAt when tx_status = 3 for particular user.

The data is as shown below :

```
id .  amount . createdAt .          user_id .      tx_status
112   500 .    2019-05-15 00:30:40  345 .          1
113 . 300      2019-05-16 06:45:29  345 .          2
116 . 600 .    2019-05-16 06:45:33  345 .          3
119 . 567 .    2019-05-17 07:56:55  345 .          1
121   500 .    2019-05-18 00:30:40  346 .          1
123 . 300      2019-05-19 06:45:29  346 .          2
124 . 600 .    2019-05-20 06:45:33  346 .          3
126 . 567 .    2019-05-21 07:56:55  346 .          1
```

The output should be :

```
id .  amount . createdAt .          user_id .      tx_status
119 . 567 .    2019-05-17 07:56:55  345 .          1
126 . 567 .    2019-05-21 07:56:55  346 .          1
```

Comment: You want to see if there are any debits or credits after the last settlement?

Comment: yes there and I want those specific debits and credits after the last settlement for each user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It uses a derived table of the maximum times at which settlement occurred, using conditional aggregation to ensure that if no settlements have occurred, that time is '1970-01-01' (so that all records will be returned).

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM transactions t1
JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(CASE WHEN tx_status = 3 THEN createdAt ELSE '1970-01-01' END) AS last_settlement
      FROM transactions t2
      GROUP BY user_id) t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.last_settlement < t1.createdAt
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
id  amount  createdAt           user_id tx_status
119 567     2019-05-17 07:56:55 345     1   
126 567     2019-05-21 07:56:55 346     1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ewWmsrtRYbZHEfrdXNdxn/0)

Comment: What if there is no transaction with status = 3?

Comment: then show all the transactions for that particular user

Comment: In your sample data, you have some invalid times, but why don't you include both transactions that are after the settlement for user 345?

Comment: There is only one transaction with id `119` for user id `345`

Comment: id `113` has an invalid time which is greater than the one which has `tx_status=3`. Perhaps you could correct those times in the sample data

Comment: @MrugeshThaker I updated my answer according to your new data and the requirement to return all records for a user with no settlements.